# Get the list of Users from Security group in active directory using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table which has the list of members of a security group. I need to do a check everyday to check if new members have been added or deleted and update the table accordingly.
Is there a way to get the list of members of a security group in Active Directory using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

[Linked server to Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190803(v=sql.105).aspx) is the usual method.

[Here](http://blog.skufel.net/2012/01/how-to-use-sql-server-to-query-active-directory/) is a somewhat better, step-by-step approach to setting it up.

Then create a view that has your LDAP query, and you should be good to go.

Here's what I use for one of my systems:

```
CREATE VIEW adsi_to_app AS
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(20), u.sAMAccountName) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS "username",
    CASE 
        WHEN (u.userAccountControl & 2) <> 0
            THEN 'Disabled'
        WHEN CASE convert(BIGINT, u.accountExpires)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN '12/31/9999'
                WHEN 9223372036854775807
                    THEN '12/31/9999'
                ELSE dateadd(mi, (convert(BIGINT, u.accountExpires) / 600000000) - 157258080 + datediff(minute, GetUTCDate(), GetDate()), 0)
                END < getdate()
            THEN 'Expired'
        ELSE 'Active'
        END "account_status"
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, '<LDAP://DC=your,DC=domain,DC=goes,DC=here>;(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(memberOf=CN=GroupName,OU=Groups,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=goes,DC=here));sAMAccountName,userAccountControl,accountExpires;subtree') u
```

The collation is because the server has case-sensitive collation.  The `ADSI` in the `OPENQUERY()` is the name of the linked server object.

Note that you may need to enable ad hoc queries to use `OPENQUERY()`.

Comment: Linked server to Active Directory is no longer supported (SQL 2012 / SQL 2014).  NetAQLAzman is near useless as a result.

Comment: @datagod MS removed support for registering SQL Server instances in LDAP.  That's what the AD Helper Service does, and that's what they removed.  They did not, as far as I can tell, remove support for the directory services provider, so they didn't remove the ability to query LDAP from SQL Server.

Comment: Well, I was unable to created a linked server and run the queries.  If you can get it working I'll buy you a beer.  You can created a linked server to LDAP in SQL2008, but not 20012.

Comment: @datagod Did you install the Client Tools Connectivity when you installed the server?  If you're in SSMS connected to your server and browse to Server Objects \ Linked Servers \ Providers, is ADsDSOObject present? That's the OLE Directory Services provider. It's only purpose is to connect to AD. I just installed SQL 2014 Express on my system, and even it has that provider.  If it's there it seems likely you have some other problem, but I really doubt it's related to SQL Server.

Comment: @Bacon Bits I set up the linked server as mentioned but i get the following error when i try to query:The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.
Do you know how i can provide the necessary permission?

Comment: @perplexedDev You can get that if you're querying across domains or if you're using SQL authentication instead of Windows authentication.  In SSMS, browse to the linked server you created (under Server Objects \ Linked Servers), right-click it, and go to Properties.  On the Security tab on the bottom, change the security context to "Be made using this security context" and then enter a domain username and password from the domain you're connecting to.

Comment: @Bacon Bits I am using Windows Authentication and the security setting is set as "Be made using the login's current security context". But I still get the error.